# sqlsrv_connect ConnectionInfo does not accept ConnectRetryCount option

Tags: php, sql-server

Reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options?view=sql-server-2017
You can pass a option with ConnectRetryCount

this is my connectioninfo array that works

```
 $connectionInfo = array( 
        "Database"=>$databaseName,
        "UID"=>$dbuser,
        "PWD"=>$dbpw,
        "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8",
        "APP"=>"BI",
        );
```

When I add this

```
"ConnectRetryCount"=>1

$connectionInfo = array( 
    "Database"=>$databaseName,
    "UID"=>$dbuser,
    "PWD"=>$dbpw,
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8",
    "APP"=>"BI",
    "ConnectRetryCount"=>1
    );
```

simply wont work

Gives me this error:
Invalid option  was passed to sqlsrv_connect.

IT SHOWS AN EMPTY SQUARE AFTER THE WORD OPTION

Gives me this error: Invalid option EmptySquareHere was passed to sqlsrv_connect.

Comment: I can't even spell php but since the default is 1 why do you need to include it in the connection info?

Comment: What are your PHP and sqlsrv extension versions? Thanks.

Comment: PHP Version 7.0.25 and sqlsrv version 4.0.8629.2

Comment: I want to Set it higher, but even with 1 gives me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanations:**

One possible reason is the version of PHP Driver. Based on [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/release-notes-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017), [Idle Connection Resiliency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-resiliency?view=sql-server-2017) feature (with config options `ConnectRetryCount` and `ConnectRetryInterval`) is added in version 4.3.

**Notes:**

I've made two test cases:

- PHP 5.2.10 with PHP Driver for SQL Server 2.0
- PHP 7.1.12 with PHP Driver for SQL Server 4.3

With PHP 5 and PHP Driver for SQL Server 2.0 `sqlsrv_connect()` fails with error message "Invalid option ConnectRetryCount was passed to sqlsrv_connect.". 
With PHP 7 and PHP Driver for SQL Server 4.3 `sqlsrv_connect()` works without errors.